# Total Amount Of Monero Wallets

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, privacy, stealth-address

Is there currently a way in which to view the total amount of Wallets that have been created for Monero and deposited too?

and/or an estimate located anywhere as to the total amount of wallets created and/or the average quantity of monero inside the average wallet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way and there won't ever be a way. 
This is becasue Monero is unlinkable, meaning no two destinations can be linked together. In other words, nobody can tell where certain Monero went to, so can't really calculate any stats.

This is achieved by utilizing [stealth addresses](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stealth-address), where the sender generates a one-time destination from the recipient's address. Unlike with Bitcoin, no Monero are actually sent to the stealth address itself (your wallet address never ever appears on the blockchain), but are sent to something derived from it (one-time public key). All the destinations (one-time public keys) look the same and this takes care of the recipient's privacy. The owner of an address is the only one able to know which one-time public keys "belong" to him, by means of a [private view key](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viewkey).

The only way to gather some partial stats would be through centralized services such as a web-wallet provider mymonero.com. They can know how much their users received, stored and sent out, because their backend stores the users private view key and updates the balance every time the user logs in (they don't publish this data, though). It's worth noting that these stats could be misleading. The user could spend his Monero by other means (through the standard wallet) and the site would have no knowledge of the changed balance until the user would log back in. Also, he could keep re-sending to himself and the site would see inflated balance, because it would have no knowledge that it's the same Monero going back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

The opacity of the block chain doesn't allow (on purpose) to determine how many wallets there are, or what the balance of a wallet is.